# Adding to the Third Column in a ListView Control

Tags: .net, vb.net

My problem is adding to the third column of a ListView control. I am making a logging system in which the user can add text to it to simply save to a text file. The application only has three controls: a ListView, a Button, and a TextBox. The application must work as follows: The user types "Data" (any text), and clicks the button to add it to the ListView. I understand how to add to the first and second column of the ListView, but I can not figure out adding to the third, fourth etc. This is all I have to work with (I only know how to add to the first two columns within the ListView):

```
ListView1.Items.Add(Now).SubItems.Add(TextBox1.Text)
```

This works perfectly fine; however, in the third column that I have labeled "Length", I want it to count the length of the characters within the second column, for every row.

Conclusion: An application that has a ListView with three Columns. The first column adds the date in which the user added the text to column two, and the third column should simply automatically count the length of characters in column two. I just do not understand how to add past the second column.

Sorry for the ambiguity, but the solution should not be that complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `AddRange` method:

```
Dim  Col1, Col2 as String
Col1 = Now.ToShortDateString()
Col2 = TextBox1.Text
ListView1.Items.Add(Col1).SubItems.AddRange({Col2, Col2.Length.ToString})
```

Col1 is the string you're adding to column 1.  Col2 is the string you're adding to column 2.  `Col2.Length.ToString` puts the  number of characters entered into column 2, into column 3.  Simply plug in the strings your code expects to add.

The AddRange method takes a collection of strings and adds each one as a separate subitem.  The collection can be a separately declared collection or an inline one like I've done using the `{}`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand this answer. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I added some elaboration.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, It just frustrates me if I do not have a clear understanding of the answer. I do not want to just copy and paste. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, one more question, could you tell me a little about the AddRange method? You seem you be more familiar about it than me. I have only used the Add method.

Comment: I added more about the addrange method.  I hope this enough for you to mark this answered. If not let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: This really helped, I am sure I will not be the only one to find this useful.